# Radius server not responding to EAP requests

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, wifi, radius, nps

We are trying to setup a wifi environment using WPA2 security using Radius server and AD authentication.

We've set up the radius server using the following guide:

https://networklessons.com/wireless/peap-and-eap-tls-on-server-2008-and-cisco-wlc/

Later when we try to access the wifi ssid it says

> Windows was unable to connect.

So I tried checking the logs at `C:\Windows\System32` folder and found the error code was 49:

> Did not match connection request policy

I changed the connection request policy condition to NAS IPv4 Address : (IP address of my AP which is trying to authenticate) and now when I tried to connect I do not see any logs being created (neither in the log file nor in the event logs).

Event viewer for NPS shows *event id 4400*, there is no other event generated.

I've tried to monitor the the radius server using NETMON tool and I could see packets with EAP protocol being sent to the radius server but it doesn't send anything back.

I also used the tool NTRADPING to test, but it says Access-reject and on monitoring the network, I could se packets with protocol RADIUS being sent and received.

I tried reinstalling the roles ADCS and NPS again but it didn't help.

I've tried almost all possible combinations of Network and Connection policies but couldn't get it to work.